# Converting a Text box to an integer value

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have two rfid card values and i want to print the sum of the two text boxes to a third text box

```
textBoxIntra.Text = Double.Parse((rfidCard.getUnsignedData(11, 0) / 1000.0)+"").ToString("N1")
textBoxExtra.Text = Double.Parse((rfidCard.getUnsignedData(11, 2) / 1000.0)+"").ToString("N1")
```

i want another textbox called bodywater to contain the sum of the values of intra and extra

if i use `bodywater.text = textBoxIntra.Text + textBoxExtra.Text ;`

then it concatenates the values instead of adding it since the types are string. how can i get the integer value of the sum in this box . Please help

Comment: Parse them to `integer` or `double` and then use additional operator. In your case, you try to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, textBoxIntra.Text is definitely a string, so you'll have to convert it to an int

```
bodywater.text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxIntra.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxExtra.Text)).ToString() ;
```

if you want a little bit more security

```
int intra = 0;
int extra = 0;

Int32.TryParse(textBoxIntra.Text, out intra);
Int32.TryParse(textBoxExtra.Text, out extra);

bodywater.Text = (intra + extra).ToString();
```

or, if you need to keep the precision in addition before converting to integer

```
double intra = 0;
double extra = 0;
Double.TryParse(textBoxIntra.Text, out intra);
Double.TryParse(textBoxExtra.Text, out extra);

bodywater.Text = Convert.ToInt32(intra + extra).ToString();
```

Last option, if you wanna set text only if intra and extra are numeric values :

```
double intra = 0;
double extra = 0;
if (Double.TryParse(textBoxIntra.Text, out intra) &&
    Double.TryParse(textBoxExtra.Text, out extra))
    bodywater.Text = Convert.ToInt32(intra + extra).ToString();
else
    bodywater.Text = "Non numeric values detected";
```

Comment: @jordanhill123 In the question : `how can i get the integer value of the sum in this box `

Comment: Agreed but it depends on the accuracy the OP needs. He doesn't state it but conceptually he can do either.

Comment: You need to convert `intra + extra` to `string` before setting `bodywater.Text` in both examples. In your first example you write `text` with a small `t` as well.

Comment: @jordanhill123 see what you mean, added this version.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `string` values to `int` using `Convert.ToInt32`. This will however throw an exception if the string value cannot be converted to `int`, eg: `12abc`.

```
bodywater.text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxIntra.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxExtra.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: I think you meant `Double` for the conversion based on the Double.Parse in the OP's question.

Comment: the question title is `Converting a Text box to an integer value`

Comment: Depends if the  OP wants casting/rounding to an int before or after adding and how much accuracy he needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse both `textbox` values into `Double` (reason for `Double` is because when you assigned values to them you parsed them to `Double`) to add them.

```
bodywater.text = (Double.Parse(textBoxIntra.Text) + Double.Parse(textBoxExtra.Text)).ToString();
```

However, if you don't want the double value. Parse it to `int`:

```
bodywater.text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxIntra.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxExtra.Text)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToInt32(textBoxIntra.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBoxExtra.Text)

The text value of the textboxes are strings and therefore is concatenated.